# PowerShell download newest file in html site

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get PowerShell to download the newest msi file from http://download.affixa.com/MSI/versions.html but I can never find the file. I can get this to download a file from a different site though. When I try to grab info form this site, I only get Google info to appear when I do not see any Google on their page. Also, I only want to download the file if I don't already have it (in same directory as script) to which I have not figured that end out because I can't even get this to work.

```
$site = (Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://download.affixa.com/MSI").Links | Where-Object {$_.href -like ‘*msi*’} | Select-Object href
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $site -Outfile "$PSScriptRoot\Affixa.msi"
```

Comment: that list is being generated during the page load. you can see where the list of files is being loaded and then sorted. since IE aint normally available on win10 ... you will likely need to use the selenium module to grab the page & parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Lee mentioned you need to use a browser/parser as the content of the page is loaded on page load.

here is what works for me (as IE is still available on Windows 10 to my knowledge).

```
# reset '$lastLink'
$lastLink = $null
while($null -eq $lastLink) {
    # set the url we want to parse
    $url = 'http://download.affixa.com/MSI/versions.html'
    # create an Internet Explorer object
    $ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
    # hide the Internet Explorer Application
    $ie.visible = $false;
    # navigate to the url specified
    $ie.navigate($url);
    # wait for the application beeing ready to use
    while($ie.Busy -eq $true) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    # select the last link of the page which matches the pattern
    $lastLink = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | Select-Object -Last 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href
    # close the Internet Explorer application
    $ie.quit()
}
# download the msi
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $lastLink -OutFile "$PSScriptRoot\Affixa.msi"
```

Comment: Interesting Guenther. I have tested this script several times now and most of the time it will error out with
```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
At line:20 char:24
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $lastLink.href -OutFile "$PSScriptRoot\Affixa- ...
```
and sometimes it will work. I set $ie.visible to true so that I could verify that the page is loading correctly and even tried extending the sleep time, which did help the reliability.

Comment: so did increasing the sleep time fix it then?

Comment: i've updated the script and removed the `where`-clause form `$lastLink` as it was slowing down the process quite a bit. also  i now select the property `href` directly and added additional wait time. i ran the script in a loop without failures.

Comment: i updated it one more time as it still did fail 1 in 100 tries - so to make sure the parsing was successful i've added a while loop. you might want to add a max. number of retries (to force the loop to quit if e.g. there is no internet access)

Comment: Great! Thanks! Failures were usually resolved during the loop. I guess there is just issues on the backend of their site.

Comment: if the answer did resolve your issue please mark it as answer.